# Ionic Button with custom colors

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

I’m trying to set dynamic colors for the `background-color` and `color` of an `ion-button` (Framework v4.0.0).
What I’ve achieved so far:

[image]

My problem: The button color overlays the button outline.
Is this an Ionic issue, how can I get around this?

**Template:**

```
<ion-button *ngFor="let d of districts" shape="round"
                (click)="districtClicked(d)"
                [ngStyle]="getDistrictStyle(d)"
                color="{{getDistrictColors(d)[0]}}">
        {{getDistrictName(d)}}
</ion-button>
```

**Method in my Component:**

```
getDistrictStyle(district: District) {
        if (district) {
            const colors = this.colorGenerator.getDistrictColors(district);
            return {
                'background-color': colors[0],
                'color': colors[1]
            };
        }
 }
```

`getDistrictColors(district: District)` simply returns an array with two colors in hex (red and white in this case).

Comment: If i'm reading the Ionic Docs it's pointing out a 'fill' methode under the ion-button element. Have you tried that? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button

Comment: Thanks, already tried. Does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but this might help someone. You can follow this tutorial by Paul Stelzer. It helped me: https://medium.com/@paulstelzer/ionic-4-how-to-add-more-colors-and-use-them-as-color-in-buttons-and-more-7175ab4ae4e7

Basically we can create new colors like this:

```
:root {
    --ion-color-gold: #ffd700;
    --ion-color-gold-rgb: 255, 215, 0;
    --ion-color-gold-contrast: #000000;
    --ion-color-gold-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --ion-color-gold-shade: #e0bd00;
    --ion-color-gold-tint: #ffdb1a;
}
.ion-color-gold {
    --ion-color-base: var(--ion-color-gold) !important;
    --ion-color-base-rgb: var(--ion-color-gold-rgb) !important;
    --ion-color-contrast: var(--ion-color-gold-contrast) !important;
    --ion-color-contrast-rgb: var(--ion-color-gold-contrast-rgb) !important;
    --ion-color-shade: var(--ion-color-gold-shade) !important;
    --ion-color-tint: var(--ion-color-gold-tint) !important;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<ion-button color="gold">We now have a gold button :)</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create custom color vairable in variable.scss in theme folder like this:

```
:root {
--ion-color-custom: #ffd700;
}
```

Note-:  custom is name of variable
and use like
Custom Button Color